# react-recharts LineChart does not render

Tags: reactjs, recharts

i'm attempting to use Recharts/LineChart for reactJs with a simple set of data, but nothing is displayed : https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-water-omrql?file=/src/App.js

Is there something wrong with the parameters ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

O, i've understood why it didn't work, i've targetted the dataKey attribute to something inexistant